# Filter Table in Sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have  one table  Abc

```
Id    Date      status
C01   Jul 3      A
C02   Jul 5      B
C03   Jul 9      A
C02   Jul 9      A
C05   Jul 3      C
C02   Jul 3      C
C03   Jul 12     C
C05   Jul 13     A
```

i want  filter this  table 
  then out  put...

```
Id    Date      Status
C01   Jul 3        A
C02   Jul 9        A
C03   Jul 12       C
C05   Jul 13       A
```

Comment: **What do you want to filter by?** What's the critiera?? Just giving us input and output and letting us **GUESS** what you want isn't really productive.....

Comment: filter by  Status A  with last  modify date

Comment: If you want that, why your output hast a "C" status ? Please edit your question with correct info and filter criteria

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want if your `Date` column is of datatype date and not a string.

```
select *
from
  (
  select *,
         row_number() over(partition by Id order by Date desc) as rn
  from Abc
  ) as T
where T.rn = 1
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/76126)

Comment: +100 if I could - how on earth did you figure that one out, from the little info the OP gave us (and you) ....

Comment: @marc_s Lucky I guess :) Tried it with the strings provided first and that did of course not work. Thought about doing some advanced alphanumeric sort but did not do that since the name of the column is `Date` and it **should** be a date/datetime.

Answer (score 0):

If you `group by` your Id and Status, you won't get the output expected. You need to get your `max date` for each Id, and the get the Status by a `Join`

```
 Select T1.Id, T1.Date, T2.Status from
    (select Id, max(Date) as 'Date'
    from Abc group by Id) T1
    INNER JOIN Abc T2 on T1.Id = T2.Id and T1.Date = T2.Date order by Id asc
```

It may fail if there's two equals `dates` for one Id, but if you're looking the `Max` this should't happen. (Or we need more information to know that to do in this cases)

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/76128)